# How to make progress indicator (downloading percentage) in Global Snackbar?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

i am trying to implement a global downloadFile() function and a global snackbar, so that the snackbar and the downloading keep working even after navigating to another widget.
the problem is the downloading progress (the downloading percentage) doesn't update at all.
this is CustomSnackBar

```
          class CustomSnackBar {
        static bool isDownloading = false;
        static String progress = "0%";
        CustomSnackBar._();
        static Future<void> downloadFile(
            BuildContext context, String fileUrl, fileName) async {
          Dio dio = Dio();
        
          isDownloading = true;
          try {
            var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            await dio
                .download(fileUrl, "${dir.path}/notifications_files/$fileName.pdf",
                    onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
              progress = '${((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)} %';
              buildErrorSnackbar(context, "empty");
            });
            isDownloading = false;
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        }

        static buildErrorSnackbar(BuildContext context, String message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              duration: const Duration(days: 100),
              backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
              content: snacBarDownloading(progress),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                textColor: kWhiteColor,
                label: 'Dismiss',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }

      Widget snacBarDownloading(String progress) {
        // print(progress);
        return Row(children: [
          const SizedBox(
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: kWhiteColor)),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text("Downloading $progress ...",
              style: const TextStyle(color: kWhiteColor))
        ]);
      }
```

and this where i call the downloading function

```
  return InkWell(
      onLongPress: () {
        if (!isDownloading &&
            widget.notificationList[index].fileUrl != null &&
            widget.notificationList[index].fileUrl!.isNotEmpty) {
          CustomSnackBar.downloadFile(
              context,
              widget.notificationList[index].fileUrl!,
              widget.notificationList[index].serviceId!);
        }
      },
```

Comment: if you want to update widget content you need to convert it into statefulwidget and call `setState` after update some value displayed.

Comment: i don't want to return a widget i just want to call a download function and display snackbar

Comment: yes, but if you want to update the info displayed into snackbar (percentage that is changing) you need a statefulwidget or any state manager.